# How to check the backward compatibility of my node app with node version

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I check what's the oldest (not latest) version of Node can my application work on? Is there a package or a Node utility which can tell me this information?

Answer (score 2):

No, in node.js there is the [process.versions](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.12/api/process.html#process_process_version) property to tell you what version you are running, for example:

```
Number(process.version.match(/^v(\d+\.\d+)/)[1])

if process.version is 'v0.11.5', then get 0.11 (Number)
```

But there is no package to tell you what's the oldest version of node your app can work on. You will have to figure it out on your own through testing, preferably unit test, in order to check the different version of node and the affect on your app. Then use the process version to match those findings.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a package like that. The only way in my opinion is to write unit test (and other kinds of test) and try to run test using different versions of node. By doing that, you make sure your code doesn't break when migrating to another version of node.

Another thing to help you to do this easily is to use NVM to setup your node. By doing that, you can easily switch between versions of node and run the test.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `npm view` to check the package versions you need to support your version of node. However, beware that using package versions that are too old will increase security issues.

`npm view <packageName>@<version> engines`

See the **npm view** [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-view) for more info.

*For example:*

`npm view jest verson` returns the latest version, in my case 27.1.0
`npm view jest engines` gives you:

```
{ node: '^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=15.0.0' }
```

Which tells you the latest version of jest, v27, supports node 10.13, 12.13, 14.15, and 15.

`npm view jest@25 engines` however, tells you it supports anything over node 8.3:

```
jest@25.5.2 { node: '>= 8.3' }
jest@25.5.3 { node: '>= 8.3' }
jest@25.5.4 { node: '>= 8.3' }
```

(this response is to an old question, but it still come up on my Google search)